# Handle multiple submit buttons with "Remote" validation in MVC4 razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two buttons in my Event form as below,

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Events", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
        }, new { @id = "updateEventForm" }))
        {

            <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @if (Model.EventID <= 0)
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, new { id = "txtCode", Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Code", Value = "E_" + new Random().Next().ToString() })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, new { id = "txtCode", Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Code" })
                        }
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" name="action:Save" id="btnSave" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Save & Next" class="btn btn-primary" name="action:SavenNext" id="btnSaveNext" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- // Modal body END -->
        }
```

In My Controller I have following action while click on "**Save**",

```
[HttpPost]
        [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Save")]
        public ActionResult SaveClick(Events objEvents)
        {
            int Result = CreateEvent(objEvents);
            if (Result == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and while click on "**Save & Next**", following action will be called,

```
 [HttpPost]
        [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "SavenNext")]
        public ActionResult SavenNextClick(Events objEvents)
        {
            int Result = CreateEvent(objEvents);
            if (Result == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse(objEvents.SubscriptionID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I have Remote validation on my model as below,

```
 [Remote("codeExist", "Events", AdditionalFields = "EventID", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Code must be unique!")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
```

If i will comment Remote validation line, then everything works perfect but if i will remain validation, then following Create() action is called(which must be called when i need to open form),

```
 public ActionResult Create(int SubscriptionID)
        {
            FillEventTypeDropDown();
            objEvents.SubscriptionID = SubscriptionID;
            return PartialView(objEvents);
        }
```

But i need to call SaveClick ana SavenNextClick, Please any help for remote validation with multiple submit button.

Comment: you can see your answer here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: @Mostafa Soghandi, I have already refrred this link, and i have done my code according to first answer. But still, it's not done.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an actionname for your HTML buttons.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" actionname="save" id="btnSave" />
<input type="submit" value="Save & Next" class="btn btn-primary" actionname="savenext" id="btnSaveNext" />
```

and have one method on controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(..., string actionname = "") {
    if(actionname == "save") then //do something
    else //do someting else

}
```

I mean that actionname parameter is going to be added to your querystring and bring the proper value based on clicked button.

Comment: It's not working and actionname is not showing as an attribute, still it returns null in controller's action.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" name="actionname" id="btnSave" />
<input type="submit" value="Save & Next" class="btn btn-primary" name="actionname" id="btnSaveNext" />
```

and controller side still remain the same as in previous answer.
actionname parameter is going to take the values from the button: so in this case Save or Save & Next

Sorry my mistake on previous answer

Comment: I have tried this also, but with remote validation, it's not working. Without remote valdiation, everything will work file.